# How can i dynamically call my css file on index.html - angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

My requirement is i need to call a css url from a variable. Actually i dont want to hard code it. As per the logged in user , the name of the css will be downloaded in local storage and from there i want to load it on index.html, how can i make this possible ?

My `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Wbuilder</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/files/css/style.css">
  // instead of this i need to call this from a variable

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not create an Angular component that dynamically generates an in-line `<script>`tag that includes a dynamically generated `@import` statement that loads the css. This component will be added to your root component template.

So the template for the dynamic css component may look like this:

```
<style>
   @import "{{dynamicCssFileLocation}}.css";
</style>
```

With this dynamic css component's selector in your mainn index.html file it should load this dynamic file from the variable `dynamicCssFileLocation`

Comment: can you give me an example for an head start

Comment: I am new in angular, i use angular cli. To my understanding when i create a new component using `ng g c comp_name` its html and ts files are created. How can i create a component for index.html ? Sorry for throwing a noob question

Comment: create a new component as you described, follow my instructions, and then include it in your root component (app.component.html typically) as a child component

Answer (score 0):

Open your main style.css( This file be under app folder ) file and write top on the code this line:-

style.css

```
@import "/assets/files/css/style.css";
```

Comment: Please connect to me on skype: jessica_storm1986 for freelance work if interested

Comment: Ok, If are you satisfy with my answer so please check mark my answer.

Comment: this is not the relevent answer :)

Answer (score -1):

This may help someone. Instead adding a file, if there are minimal dynamic css you can include it. A dynamic generated CSS at the controller can be bind to the HTML View using ng-bind-html attribute with in the style tag.

Have a look at http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/angularjs/adding-dynamic-generated-csscascading-style-sheet-angularjs-view-example for **Demo** and **Sample Code**

**HTML**

```
    <style ng-bind-html="myStyle"></style>
    <span>Enter the background colour value:</span>
    <span><input type = "text" ng-keyup="updateChanges()" ng-model = "bgcolour"></span>
    <br/>
    <div class="codeexpertz">
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.bgcolour = '11acfd';
    $scope.updateChanges = function(){
        $scope.myStyle= '.codeexpertz { background-color: #' + $scope.bgcolour + '; height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 1px #000 solid}';
    }
    $scope.updateChanges();
```

Comment: This answer requires angular2+